# how to create a deep-link which redirects to AppStore

Tags: ios, deep-linking

I successfully created a deep-link which redirects to GooglePlay if the application is not installed on android.
The deep-link is:

```
intent://www.httpscheme.com/my_service?myrequest#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.my.package;end
```

According to what I found on the web, I though that I could do the following:

```
DeepLink://www.httpscheme.com/my_service?myrequest#itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/myapp/idmyapp
```

This deep-link works if the application is installed but doesn't redirect to AppStore if the application is not installed.

What is the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a javascript/script, using Pinterest as an example:

```
function myFunction(){

        window.location.replace('Pinterest://');

        setTimeout("window.location = 'https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/pinterest/id429047995?mt=8';", 1000); 

    }
```

P.S. have you got that intent working on Opera on mobile?

Comment: I didn't check with Opera but with Chrome. Anyway, on Android, when you try to access a feature in application and the application is not installed, you are redirected to Google Play to download it. That doesn't work that way on iOS?

Comment: not as far as i know, the way Pinterest do it is as i said above

Comment: Actually, Pinterest uses [Branch.io](http://branch.io) for this. It's basically the same flow as you mention, but with some extra steps to avoid showing nasty error messages.

Answer (score 0):

This only works on Android with the Play Store, behaves different depending on whether you are using Chrome or another browser, and is somewhat unreliable in any case. Apple has no equivalent feature for the App Store.

As mentioned in another answer, what you essentially need to do is attempt to launch the app and then redirect to the App Store if this attempt fails. This used to be simple, but now iOS 9.2+ will show you a confirmation dialog before opening the app, and this dialog does not block javascript from running so your user will be forwarded to the App Store fallback URL before ever getting a chance to launch the app. Apple appears to have done this on purpose to drive adoption of their new Universal Links standard.

You might consider using a free deep linking service like [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the team). This greatly simplifies a lot of the technical details you would otherwise need to handle yourself.